# Angular object array calling

Tags: angular, typescript

If I got interface :

```
export interface Banner {
html: string;
}

  banner = {} as Banner;
```

and I save `strings` in to it like this :

```
  this.banner.html = xmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

`console.log(this.banner.html)` gives different strings.

**Then I want to call these different strings and put them into iframe.**

I am trying to to do it with `ViewChildren` and `querying` :

```
  @ViewChildren('html') htmls: QueryList<ElementRef>;

 this.htmls.map((elem, index) => {
       elem.nativeElement.src = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(this.navSrv.banner.html);
     });
```

**Then I get only the last string not all of them :**

```
console.log("showing only one html string :", elem.nativeElement.src.toString())
```

How to get all different strings and put them all into `iframes`, not the last one ?

Edit with some more explanations :

**NavService.ts :**

```
export interface Banner {
    html: string;
    }

      banner = {} as Banner;
      this.banner.html = xmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
      console.log(this.banner.html)
```

**Output is normal, I get all strings like this :**

html : value, html: value..... x n.

**Components.ts :**

```
console.log(this.navSrv.banner.html)
```

**Output :**

last html: value, only 1 output.

---

**In service :**

html: value,

html: value,

html: value, N times....

**In component :**

html: value,

html: value,

html: value,  <--- only the last one.

Comment: what is the output of `this.navSrv.banner.html`?

Comment: If I use this.banner.html i my service the output is normal : it is showing all different strings. If I use this.navSrv.banner.html in my component It only shows the last one.

Comment: I don't get you, you mean `this.navSrv.banner.html` is a string then in component a last string? Why is it a last string?, Could you post the output of `this.navSrv.banner.html` in here.

Comment: Watch at edit. I tried to explain

Comment: It seems like you're posting an array of strings instead of a single string, better post a picture of the console log of `this.navSrv.banner.html` for clarification